# Files input missing from Request Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel to make form upload, it worked well before. But, now it doesn't work.

I've tried to debug my code using `dd($request->all()`, but my `photo` file was missing.

This is my `view` code

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal form-bordered" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-2 col-md-1 control-label" style="text-align: left;position: relative;right: -8px;">
      <div class="row">
        <span class="fa fa-file-image-o" aria-hidden="true" style="position: relative;font-size: 20px;top: 0px;text-align: left;color: #ADADAD;"></span>
      </div>
    </label>
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-11">
      <input name="photo" value="" class="form-control" style="padding-top: 5px;height: auto;" type="file">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

and this is the controller code

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    ...
    dump($request->all()); 

    if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
        $file = $request->file('photo');

        $timestamp = 21;
        $name = $timestamp. '-' .$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $Members->photo = $name;
        $n = Image::make(Input::file('photo'));
        $n->resize(330, 330);
        $path = 'uploads/'.$name;
        $n->save($path);
    }
}
```

**PS**. I was modified php.ini file before, does it matter?

Comment: try removing the empty value attribute

Comment: Form action is empty. Is that on purpose?

Comment: @Mahmoud Sehsah where's your input with type="submit", or did you do that with JS ?? how you've done submitting ?

Comment: Please include more of your blade template, as well as any FormRequest/validation you may be using. Your form doesn't have an action, so by all rights you shouldn't be getting to the dd() at all since a form with an empty action will just refresh the page.

Comment: thnsks for all ,it's work after edite in php.ini